# Inferring (without type widening) a property from an object

Tags: typescript

- I have a type `MrType<T extends boolean>`
- I have a func `MrFn(obj?: { lol: boolean }): MrType<typeof obj.lol>`

I am trying to infer whether the `lol` property on the supplied object (if supplied at all) is `true` or `false`

However I am hitting a wall due to type widening

```
type Magic<T> = T extends { lol: infer U } ? U : false;

const trueObj = { lol: true };
const falseObj = { lol: false };

// should pass
const a: Magic<typeof trueObj> = true; // ok
const b: Magic<typeof falseObj> = false; // ok
const c: Magic<{ lol: true }> = true; // ok
const d: Magic<{ lol: false }> = false; // ok

// should fail
const e: Magic<typeof falseObj> = true; // does not fail
const f: Magic<typeof trueObj> = false; // does not fail
const g: Magic<{ lol: false }> = true; // ok (fails)
const h: Magic<{ lol: true }> = false; // ok (fails)
```

My `trueObj` and `falseObj` get their properties inferred as `boolean`, which means my `Magic<T>` is unable to detect whether you set `true` or `false`

Is there a way to correct my solution or is this a limitation within TS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in TypeScript 3.4+ with the new `as const` type assertion:

```
type Magic<T> = T extends { lol: infer U } ? U : false;

const trueObj = { lol: true } as const;
const falseObj = { lol: false } as const;

// should pass
const a: Magic<typeof trueObj> = true; // ok
const b: Magic<typeof falseObj> = false; // ok
const c: Magic<{ lol: true }> = true; // ok
const d: Magic<{ lol: false }> = false; // ok

// should fail
const e: Magic<typeof falseObj> = true; // ok (fails)
const f: Magic<typeof trueObj> = false; // ok (fails)
const g: Magic<{ lol: false }> = true; // ok (fails)
const h: Magic<{ lol: true }> = false; // ok (fails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will not use literal if the value is mutable (and although `trueObj` is `const` the object is still mutable).

The simplest solution is to change how you create the object, using a function that will infer the correct literal type for the property :

```
function makeLol<T extends boolean>(o: { lol: T }) {
    return o
}
const trueObj = makeLol({ lol: true }); // typed as { lol: true }
const falseObj = makeLol({ lol: false }); // typed as { lol: false }
```

Comment: I figured as much, trying avoid having to do this however